# Xcode 4.4 template location

Tags: xcode, templates

I'm currently trying to install some Xcode templates for SFML, but I cannot find the template directory that works. It seems like every tutorial offers a different location (Which I know is from Apple changing it),  but I was wondering what the 4.4/4.5 directory is.

Answer (score 8):

xctemplates are now in Xcode itself.

Right click the Xcode application, click "Show Package Contents", then navigate to

```
Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates
```

From there you can drop File Templates or Project Templates in the respective directory.

Comment: Xcode does not seem to be finding them. They aren't showing up in the GUI at all.

Answer (score 6):

User project templates should go in the following location:

```
/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/GroupName
```

Where GroupName is the group on the left side of the New Project Assistant. You can create your own group name or use one of Apple's group names. By placing your templates in the user template location, your project templates won't get overwritten when you update Xcode to a new version.